# Get applescript to listen for iMessage read receipts

Tags: applescript, imessage

I have written an applescript application that checks an API of the weather the messages it to a friend.

My friend's iphone sends read receipts, how can i get applescript to run some code eg `say "The message has been read"` when he sends a read receipt

Comment: Or even checking the time of the latest read receipt in a conversation

Comment: You should look script examples provided by Apple about how to use message handlers. See in folder  Library/Application Scripts / com.apple.iChat. There are several scripts. it looks to be iChat, but it also works for Message.

Comment: I know, and  i looked through them i can't find anything to do with read receipts

Comment: I do not want to read the most recent message sent to me, i want to know when/if the person i sent a message to reads it(Provided that they send receipts)

Comment: What should be the form of their receipts ? I guess it should just be a new message. then you can use the example and track, for each message received, which one is a receipt confirmation. not ?

Comment: When i send a message the blue bar goes across the top, under the message i just sent it says `delivered`. When my friend reads it it sends back a read receipt and the `delivered` changes to `read`, its built in.

Comment: It is not a message back

Comment: @pbell [imgur example photos](http://imgur.com/a/rVTra)

Comment: I made several tests, but I am not 100% sure (all my tests are done with single account !). Apparently, none of the handler available can do what you want to do with message status. Sorry

Comment: What about where the chat is stored, could i read that some how. surly it must have it recorded somewhere. **And thanks**

Comment: I tried through interface scripting : not possible because, in the Messages window, the area where message are display is just a container for html, the html itself is not available through GUI scripting. then I found where messages are stored : ~library/Messages/chat.db-wal.  you must investigate into  this SQL database to find format (not documented) and try to find where contents of message windows are stored and how. I don't think it is doable. Sorry. Still, if you want to dig into, check with shell database command sqlite3.